# Configure anonymous authentication to use app pool identity for a specific site

Tags: iis, authentication, powershell, iis-7.5

Instead of flipiping the switch in the GUI to tell IIS to use the Application Pool Identity for Anonymous authentication, I'd like to do this in a powershell script.

[Scott Forsyth posted a solution which changes the default for all sites.](https://serverfault.com/a/238672/45060)

How can I do the same for a specific site only? With powershell ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -name username -value "" -location MyLocation
```

I simply used the site's name as `MyLocation`, andI had to reopen IIS Manager to see the change in the UI.